Given f(z) is a continuous function in $\mathbb{C}$ with property $\lim_{z \to \infty} zf(z) = k$
Given a continuous complex-valued function $f$ such that $\lim_{z \to \infty} zf(z) = k$ and a curve D $z = Re^{it}, 0 \leq t \leq \theta$ oriented counter clockwise, Show that
$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_D f(z) dz = i \theta k$ ($\theta \neq 0$)
Here is my proof but I’m not sure whether this works?
Given any $\epsilon > 0, \exists N : \forall |z| \geq |zf(z) - k| < \frac{\epsilon}{\theta}$
Change coordinates in the integral
$| i \int_0^{\theta} f(Re^{i t}) Re^{it} dt - i\theta k |$
=| $\int_0^{\theta} f(Re^{it}) Re^{it} - k dt$|
$\leq \int_0^{\theta} |Re^{it} f(Re^{it}) - k|dt $
Since z can be expressed as $Re^{it}$ and $|z|= R$ it follows from assumption that the integrand is less that  $\frac{\epsilon}{\theta}$ for $R > N$. And the integral is less than ε.
Also I had a question on how continuity of f(z) is important in this question?
Thanks!

The continuity of $f$ guarantees that $\int_D f(z) dz$ exists.

I would mention what happens when $\theta$ is zero

it also looks like you changed the variable of integration from $t$ to $\theta$ at some point, which is wrong. as of now, the last two integrals are independent of $t$

@CSquared sorry i made an error earlier it should have been t and not θ. And i think it’s assumed that $\theta \neq 0$. I have added that as well. Apologies for the confusion

we are typically only interested in integrating (at least) continuous complex valued functions. As long as the real and imaginary parts are integrable (in whatever stronger sense you want to consider integrability of complex valued functions), this proof carries through
